# Issue with Selenium Webdriver on Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

This is my first attempt to automate something using Selenium Webdriver. I've downloaded Eclipse and the latest selenium standalone server jar and webdriver jar. This is what my project looks like so far:

[image]

When I press play, this is the error I get:

http://justpaste.it/r2cu

This is the Firefox version I have (I cannot change the firefox version, this is the one the company I work for uses):

[image]

Am I missing some configuration? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running `selenium.jar`? You need to start it on the command line, it is used by your code to communicate with the browser.

Comment: @reinierpost hmm I didn't know that ... all the tutorials I saw on youtube they just mentioned the Eclipse part ... do you have any link showing how I can do that?

Comment: Google for "selenium jar", you'll find "selenium-standalone-<version-number>.jar", that is the one. I have to go now but it should be in the documentation.

Comment: @reinierpost Thanks, I found how to do that, but even running the standalone jar, the error still persists

Comment: You definitely do not need 'selenium-standalone.jar', or indeed any other processes running: `The Selenium Server is needed in order to run either Selenium RC style scripts or Remote Selenium WebDriver ones.` Almost certainly this is a Firefox conflict with your Driver. FF 38.6 is new for ESR but old by normal standards, whereas Driver 2.50.1 is about 3 days old. Can you switch to the normal FF dist channel or else downgrade your Driver?

Comment: Thanks for correcting, I've been working with Remote WebDriver ...

Comment: please verify that the port is open . maybe other program use the same port Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Comment: @AndrewRegan I'll check if I can downgrade de driver, because I cannot change the FF dist channel nor the FF version, it's the company standards =/, but I'll try to downgrade de driver, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the stack trace your provided, it seems like fireFox Version + Selenium jar Version IS NOT Compatible. In Our Project we got FireforNotConnected exception when our browser got automatically updated by system, so we have to degrade our browser version to Compatible one. But in your case you can not change the Browser Version, so instead just try with different version of Selenium jar. It Might work with some of the old versions of Selenium Jar.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if your using Firefox `38.6.0` (ESR) to record using Selenium IDE (I prefer 'Selenium Builder' instead), that doesn't mean that playback is going to work on that version of Firefox.   If IDE is recording any native events (non-Javascript browser events), then it is a known issue that those events are no longer supported except on Firefox [31.6.0](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/31.6.0esr/) (ESR), which is the last supported version of Firefox native events for Selenium.

Comment: I'm just using webdriver, the Selenium IDE was just mentioned because I used to work with it, but in this scenario it's all webdriver, even creating a new class just with the basic command to open the browser, nothing related to IDE :-)

Comment: Thats ok, my answer still applies.  I don't know if my answer is really the solution to your problem, but at least now you can try the solution if nobody else gives you a better, more direct answer.